# Query and Import Range: values firm a few first rows are being merged

Tags: google-sheets

I am using this formula to import select columns from one Google Sheet to another:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1Y06zLsfEBPL8txxc6V0K6544iNjnNDGRYcKHtdixrOg","Reporting!A:S"),"select Col1, Col3, Col4, Col6, Col7, Col19")
```

1. Does anyone know why the values in the First and Second row of the columns are being merged automatically?

Ex: If A1 = "Socks" and A2 = "Hats" in the parent Google Sheet, then cell A1 in the imported range Google Sheet would be = "Socks Hats". Other than the first two rows, everything else looks good.

Comment: Can you post an example spreadsheet where this happens? Are you sure there isn't a hidden other line in the text content of A1 in the source?

Answer (score 1):

I think yor problem is data with empty cells, `query` formula can't automatically detect the header of your table. Try this:

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1Y06zLsfEBPL8txxc6V0K6544iNjnNDGRYcKHtdixrOg","Reporting!A:S"),"select Col1, Col3, Col4, Col6, Col7, Col19", 1)`